# How to extract text using xpath from webpage written in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xpath, google-voice

Previously, google voice allowed you to extract sms codes using a "div" Recently, they switched to an ARIA-based framework using AngularJS. How would I extract the string containing all my sms codes from the webpage?

Here is the command I have been using along with my target xpath:

```
var search2 = document.evaluate('//*[@id="messaging-view"]/div/md-content/div/gv-conversation-list/md-virtual-repeat-container/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/gv-text-conversation-item/gv-conversation-item/div/div[2]/ng-transclude/gv-conversation-item-detail/gv-annotation/text()',
  document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

[Here is the result I see on my Chrome Developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNSOR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Mozilla documentation on XPath in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript). What you are getting back is called a node iterator. This is probably the most common return type for an XPath query if you specify `ANY_TYPE` as you did. To make your code work as is you can do the following:

```
// im putting your query in a variable for readability
var query = '//*[@id="messaging-view"]/div/md-content/div/gv-conversation-list/md-virtual-repeat-container/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/gv-text-conversation-item/gv-conversation-item/div/div[2]/ng-transclude/gv-conversation-item-detail/gv-annotation/text()';
var search2 = document.evaluate(query, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();

while (thisNode) {
    console.log(thisNode.textContent); // probably will be a text node
    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
}
```

Alternatively you could specify your result type as a `STRING_TYPE` to simply it.

```
// im putting your query in a variable for readability
var query = '//*[@id="messaging-view"]/div/md-content/div/gv-conversation-list/md-virtual-repeat-container/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/gv-text-conversation-item/gv-conversation-item/div/div[2]/ng-transclude/gv-conversation-item-detail/gv-annotation/text()';
var search2 = document.evaluate(query, document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);

console.log(search2.stringValue);
```

Comment: When I look at xpathresult in console, it says " stringValue
:
[Exception: TypeError: Failed to read the 'stringValue' property from 'XPathResult': The result type is not a string. at XPathResult.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]"